# Second div is appearing on screen before previous div's get loded

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to print "center1" div after loaded first container div.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <p>here is the Parent Div Container</p>

    <div class="center1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">

                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                                <b><span style="font-size: larger;">
                                        Small business product selector FAQs</span></b>
                                <hr style="margin-top: 1rem;">
                                <h4 class="panel-title" style="margin-top: 2rem;
                                                            font-size: medium;">
                                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                        href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                        <b>What information do I need to use the Small Business Product
                                            Selector?</b>
                                    </a>
                                </h4>

                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p>All you need to use the product selector is your knowledge of the possible
                                        financial needs of your
                                        business.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                       



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--Child Container Ends here-->
    </div>
    <!-- Proposed Product selector FAQs component starts here:-->
</div><!--Parent Container Ends here-->
```

But I'm not getting output like above code. Second div appears first on screen for some second after that first div is loaded. Please let me know how I can solve this issue

Comment: Can you add more details to the question like what you are trying to achieve? Or more info on the behaviour

Comment: I am trying to display both div on one page. but when I'm running application second div that is center1 which appear first on the screen after that first div that is container is appearing on screen. I want to display or load both div in sequence.

Comment: So center-1 div which is a child of container div is loading before the parent does like 

<Parent-Div class=container (loads after child)>
    <Child-Div class=center-1 (This loads before parent?)></Child-Div>
</Parent-Div>

Comment: Is this what you are saying?

Comment: yes, and I got the solution for that. I set min-height for second div.